# Filepicker.io — How To Get An S3 URL onSuccess?

Tags: filepicker.io

How would I go about getting Filepicker.io to return an S3 URL instead of the www.filpicker.io/app/api/... default?

My files are uploading to S3 just fine (super easy, actually), but the URL that the fpfiles object contains is not my S3 URL.

I suppose I could just Frankenstein it together myself so I can insert it into my DB, but that seems messy.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('#BTN_upload').click(function(){
    filepicker.setKey('MY_FILEPICKER.IO_KEY');
    filepicker.pickAndStore(
         //Picker Options
         { extensions: ['.png'], container: 'modal', multiple: true },

         //Store Options
         {location: 'S3', path: '/filepicker/', filename:'my_filename.png'},

         //On Success
         function(fpfiles){
             console.log(JSON.stringify(fpfiles));

         },

         //On Error
         function(fperror){
             console.log(JSON.stringify(fperror));
         }
    );
});
```

**BONUS QUESTION**
How do I go about setting the filename as I'd like, not as Filepicker.io defaults to the uniqueid_originalFilename.png. I'd like to handle my filenames myself but there doesn't seem to be any way to override the default.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the S3 key. A simple concatenation of your s3 url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/your_own_bucket/" + s3key will do it.

Regarding your other question, if you set the "path" option, that will tell filepicker where to store the file.

Comment: Hi Liyan, I eventually figured out that the key was also being returned in the FPFiles object so it's easy enough to Frankenstein it, but it would be more elegant (and intuitive) if it was simply returned in the object. With regard to the filenames, that's not exactly true. When using the pickAndStore method for multiple uploads the path parameter must end in '/' or it throws an exception. You guys are working on this and in the meantime a solution of using pick and then .store in the pick callback seems like it might work but I haven't had time to test it yet.